# The state of process when CPU resumes execution after interrupt

Tags: operating-system

When CPU receives an interrupt, it completes execution of the current instruction and saves all the relevant process information of the current process on the stack, puts it in suspend state and moves on to service the interrupt. After servicing the interrupt, the CPU resumes execution of the original instruction, hence state changes from suspend to run. Can this state change be not done in any case? I read somewhere that this state change may not always be true. How?

Comment: 'After servicing the interrupt, the CPU resumes execution of the original instruction' well often it does return to the next instruction, but it may return to a different thread that may belong to a different process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very little of what you said is correct. First of all, the processor may or may not complete the instruction. Some processors have lengthy instructions that are interruptible.

I don't know of any operating system that puts a process in a suspended state when an interrupt occurs. Usually the current process handles the interrupt. Some operating system  have a stripped down process context during interrupts but the processor believes the current process is handling the interrupt.

The interrupt handler usually ends with a return from interrupt instructions that returns from kernel mode and resumes the interrupted process execution stream.

Comment: 'Usually the current process handles the interrupt'?    Interrupts do not have a process context, in general.

Comment: Given that task-switching is usually implemented in software (at least on x86 as far as I know) you can't strictly say that "processor believes" that the current process is still being executed since processor is not aware of processes at all. So saying that "the current process handles the interrupt" might be somewhat inaccurate and confusing since the code being executed doesn't actually belong to the process while some aspects of the "context" still might.

Comment: What is the state of the process which was being executed before the interrupt occurred during the time CPU services the interrupt?

Comment: @Curious either running or, if the core handling the interrupt was idle because there are more cores free than ready/running threads, then halted, (ie, 'idle' thread).

Comment: On Linux maybe. However, the processor views the interrupt as being handled by the current process's context. However, when the process handles the interrupt, the address registers in place are those of the current process. If the interrupt handler wanted to, it could access the user mode address space of the process executing when the interrupt occurred.